# Биометрическая авторизация

Tags: java, android

```
private BiometricPrompt biometricPrompt;
pribate BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo promptInfo = createPromptInfoBuilder().build();

public BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder createPromptInfoBuilder(){
    return new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder ()
            .setTitle(context.getString(R.string.sign_in_when_biometric))
            .setNegativeButtonText(context.getString(R.string.cancel));
}

biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo);// вызов диалога
```

1) Возможно ли обойтись без диалога? У нас своеобразный дизайн под данную авторизацию..
2) Как можно настроить стиль для данного диалога? Цвет текста, стиль кнопок..

Использую: `implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-alpha04'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ответ на второй вопрос:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/Alert.Dialog</item>
        <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/Alert.Dialog</item>
</style>

<style name="Alert.Dialog" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/app_white_mode_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/app_white_mode_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/Alert.Button.Positive</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/Alert.Button.Negative</item>

    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/Alert.Button.Positive</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/Alert.Button.Negative</item>    
  </style>

<style name="Alert.Button.Positive" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
    <item name="rippleColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="Alert.Button.Negative" parent="Alert.Button.Positive">
    <item name="rippleColor">#F44336</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#F44336</item>
</style>
```

> В моем случае `android:textColor`темы активити белая и из-за этого
>   title диалога сливался с фоном диалога.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: прикрепите скрин, чтоли

Comment: вопрос по поводу авторизации - это вообще сильно сложно реализовать, а то я хочу тоже такую штуку давно уже сделать, но все никак не могу дойти))

Comment: Используя, выше указанную библиотеку, можно часа за 2 изучить и сделать.